# Jenkins declarative pipeline: npm command not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So I have set up this jenkins ec2 instance, `ssh` into it, globally installed `node` and set `PATH`. But when executing my pipeline, it gives me `npm command not found` error.

I put `echo $PATH` in my pipeline and the result is:

> /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

Which looks correct.

For reference, here's my very simple pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }

  environment {
    PATH = "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/bin:${env.PATH}"
  }

  stages {
    stage('Test npm') {
      steps {
        sh """
          echo $PATH
          npm --version
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate with any help.

Comment: Check which user Jenkins is running as - `whoami`.

Comment: @DibakarAditya Hi, `whoami` results in `jenkins`. Btw I installed node under user `ec2-user`. Might this be the problem?

Comment: Apparently it is.

Comment: I see, am I supposed to tell jenkins to use the environment I set under another user?

Comment: Yes, provided the Jenkins user has appropriate permissions to the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dibakar Adtya pointed, the problem is when jenkins executes a pipeline, it's under the user `jenkins`, whereas I configured `node` under another user, `ec2-user`, and `jenkins` doesn't have access to `ec2-user`'s bin. Thank you @Dibakar!

A more elegant solution is to use [Jenkins NodeJS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin). It saves you from the environment hassles. Now the pipeline is:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'master' }

  tools { nodejs "nodejs" }

  stages {
    stage('Test npm') {
      steps {
        sh """
          npm --version
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```